# Coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+x)^{21} + (1+x)^{22} + ... + (1+x)^{30}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

How do I find the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{21} + (1+x)^{22} + ... + (1+x)^{30}$?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^5$ will be

$$\sum_{n=21}^{30}\binom n5$$

Comment: Just use the formula for sum of a geometric series.....and then obtain the required coefficient from the result of this sum.

Answer (score 3):

Use binomial theorem we have : the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+x)^n$ is $\binom{n}{5}$. Then we have:

$$\sum_{i=21}^{30}\binom{i}{5}=682017$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=21}^{30}(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{21}\cdot\dfrac{(1+x)^{9+1}-1}{(1+x)-1}=\dfrac{(1+x)^{21}\{(1+x)^{10}-1\}}x$$

So, we need the coefficient of $x^6$ in $$(1+x)^{21}\{(1+x)^{10}-1\}=(1+x)^{31}-(1+x)^{10}$$

which will be $$\binom{31}6-\binom{21}6$$

---

Alternatively, the coefficient of $x^5$ will be

$$\sum_{n=21}^{30}\binom n5$$

We can use the [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) to equate the two seemingly different results.

Comment: Could you please explain the first method in more detail? I am not able to understand it.

Comment: @SachinChaudhary, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression and pinpoint your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$,

hence the coefficient of $x^5$ is $\binom{n}{5}$.

Threrfore the coefficient you are looking for is given by

$\binom{21}{5}+\binom{22}{5}+...+\binom{30}{5}$